# What's the difference between getting graphics drivers from the new ppa vs from Additional Drivers?

Tags: drivers, updates, graphics, ppa

I've heard a lot of hype about the new PPA, but is it any better/different than using the Additional Drivers tab of the Software and Updates program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the new PPA you get more updated, easer to install Drivers. and be sure you won't break your system, :D

Comment: @Prime624 you welcome